# In which version od Android SDK was SDK Setup.exe and SDK Manager.exe introduced?

Tags: android, sdk, version, revision

Since I am currently working with legacy Android code that depends on very specific revision of Android SDK I would need to know in **which version of Android SDK** were these two exe files introduced:

**SDK Setup.exe**

**SDK Manager.exe**

Comment: its not based on android SDK its based on ADT plugin in Eclipse which introduced this separate in may be after ADT 14.0.0

Comment: I am almost certain you're wrong. For instance, Revision 15 of SDK contains these exe files. Also I am not using ADT at all in my projects.

Comment: yes, i m wrong. I was just saying you on based that you using Eclipse. sorry for that. thanks for correcting me. But i got that cos when you update ADT, it asks to always update the SDK and I havent ever used that files seprately, I will always use SDK manager from Eclipse, andADT plugins are update also based on SDK. In fact, the versions are also same. thanks :)